# inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm new to Hibernate, I'm trying to do a "simple" user insertion to oracle database I have created.

I created all the necessary files with Netbeans Hibernate wizards:
hibernate.cfg.xml, hibernate,reveng.xml, Users.hbm.xml, Users.java

If I insert user with the oracle sql developer, I can get this user from java code. But if I'm trying to insert a user I get the error: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY.

Partial Users.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="HibernateDB.Users" schema="SYSTEM" table="USERS">
    <id name="userid" type="int">
      <column name="USERID" precision="9" scale="0"/>
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    ...
```

Partial Users.java:

```
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private int userid;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Serializable dateOfBirth;
    private Serializable registrationDate;
    ...
```

Partial insertUser method (all parameters are strings):

```
    session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Calendar dOfBirth = Calendar.getInstance();
    dOfBirth.set(Integer.parseInt(year_of_birth), Integer.parseInt(month_of_birth), Integer.parseInt(day_of_birth));
    Calendar regDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Timestamp dOfBirthTS = new Timestamp(dOfBirth.getTimeInMillis());
    Timestamp regDateTS = new Timestamp(regDate.getTimeInMillis());
    Users user = new Users();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.setFirstName(first_name);
    user.setLastName(last_name);
    user.setDateOfBirth(dOfBirthTS);
    user.setRegistrationDate(regDateTS);
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    ans = user.getUserid();
    tx.commit();
```

Users Table in the database:

```
USERID NUMBER(9,0) - the primary key
USERNAME VARCHAR(200)
PASSWORD VARCHAR(200)
FIRST_NAME VARCAHR(200)
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(200)
DATE_OF_BIRTH TIMESTAMP
REGISTRATION_DATE TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the real problem therefore I could solve it!

Real problem: Table have TIMESTAMP fields, hibernate generate them as Serializable, which produce the error as Serializable is not a TIMESTAMP.

Fix: I have add a mapping rule to hibernate.reveng.xml:

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-schema="SYSTEM"/>
    <type-mapping> 
        <sql-type jdbc-type="OTHER" hibernate-type="java.util.Calendar" /> 
    </type-mapping>
    ...
```

it also work's with Date type not just Calender (maybe more types I didn't try).

Conclusion: shouldn't relay on auto generating mechanism.

Comment: you can accept your own answer to gain reputation points. You want the check mark by 'counter' (currently 0) at outside the top-left margin. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

This problem may occur when we declare an Object type property with `@Column` annotation.

```
@Column(name="job_category")
private MiscTypeSetup jobCategory;
```

We should declare with `@JoinColumn` annotation.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="job_category")
private MiscTypeSetup jobCategory;
```

Comment: Thanks. Hibernate should give error during beans creation

Answer (score 1):

I've received this error before when accidentally attempting to persist an entity with one of it's fields having a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Long as the data type instead. It might help.

```
private Long userid;
```

Comment: Still not working, I now get null from user.getUserid(); meaning the generator class="increment" not working (probably because userid in Users.hbm.xml is of type "int", I have try to change it to other types then I get the inconsistent datatypes error again).
I don't understand something, I didn't created the Users class it was generated automatically with hibernate, so how come I need to make changes in this class, it's not suppose to create Users class with the right types respected to database table?