# How to set Integer parameter as null in Hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got an entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "smsc.security_users")
    public class User {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;

        @Column(name = "enabled")
        private int enabled;

        @Column(name = "master_id", nullable = true)
        private Integer master_id;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "passwordExpiration")
        private Date passwordExpiration;

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        ...
```

I'm talking about `master_id`. And this is my DAO method:

```
public void add(String userName, String password, Integer master_id) {
        Session session = null;
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "INSERT INTO smsc.security_users(id,username,password,enabled,passwordExpiration,master_id) VALUES(smsc.SeqDictID.nextval+1,:userName,:password,1,:passwordExpiration,:master_id)")
                .setString("userName", userName)
                .setString("password", Sha1.getHash(password))
                .setTimestamp("passwordExpiration", DateUtil.getTomorrow())
                .setInteger("master_id", master_id);
        int updated = query.executeUpdate();

    }
```

Log says:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

and puts pointer at this line:

```
.setInteger("master_id", master_id);
```

`master_id` must be null sometimes. So how can I set null?

Comment: Try: .setParameter("master_id", master_id)

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev, `ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected number got binary`

Comment: a workaround for this would be to create 2 separate methods and specify null inside SQL query string

Comment: Maybe it will help (look at answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077721/inconsistent-datatypes-expected-number-got-binary

Comment: @Funtik, ok. But I thought we can put a java reference as parameter that might be null.

Comment: Issuing an `insert` statement via Hibernate is odd. Why don't you do: `User user = new User(/* parameters */); session.save(user);`?

Comment: I think the problem with master_id is solved, and now there is problem in .setTimestamp("passwordExpiration", DateUtil.getTomorrow()) - see the link above.

Comment: @EtienneMiret, this method handles web-form parameters. I don't want to transfrom web-form object to entity object.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you check the documentation of the Query class, setInteger() method,

```
Query setInteger(String name,int val)
```

It takes a name and a **primitive type int**, as parameters.

When you pass a wrapper type Integer, whose value is null, during **autoboxing**, a null pointer Exception occurs.

For example:

```
Integer x = null;
int y = x;  // gives a nullpointer exception.
```

You could use

```
Query setParameter(String name,
                   Object val,
                   Type type);
```

method to set null values.

**See Also:**

[Hibernate: How to set NULL query-parameter value with HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123438/hibernate-how-to-set-null-query-parameter-value-with-hql)

Comment: Well, I know that part with null. My Integer migth be null. That's why I chose wrapper as it's type.

Comment: Did you try the setParameter() with the three arguments? According to the document it should definitely work.

Comment: What type it should be?

Comment: Can you try IntegerType.INSTANCE, i guess Hibernate.INTEGER is deprecated. Have updated my answer with a link, that's just a workaround though.

Answer (score 13):

For a null object, specify it as:

```
query.setParameter("name", object, StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER);
```

`StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER` replaced `Hibernate.INTEGER` (etc)