# Hibernate expected NUMBER got BINARY on null field

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't understand why Hibernate is trying to set this field as a VARBINARY when it is null.

The Java data type is BigDecimal
The Oracle data type is Float

It is being set like this:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("blah").setParameter("target_field", object.sourceValue)
```

again - sourceValue is a BigDecimal, and when i debug it the value is null.

when it tries to execute this update, I get oracle error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

this is what shows up for this property in the console log:

```
o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
```

IF I do this silly hack in Java before I execute the update:

```
if (object.sourceValue == null) object.sourceValue = new java.math.BigDecimal(0);
```

Then it runs fine. So the cause of this error is definitely not anything else than hibernate doing something wrong when the field is null.

How do I fix this so I can set the field to null without hibernate mishandling it?

In the DB, the field is nullable.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123438/hibernate-how-to-set-null-query-parameter-value-with-hql

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667914/how-to-set-integer-parameter-as-null-in-hibernate-query

Comment: The first link has to do with where clauses, but the second link does apply. The problem is in their solution they talk about using some setParameter (string, object, type) method, which does not exist unless it's available only in a newer hibernate version than I am forced to use (4.3.11)

Comment: Yeah, that confused me as well. My takeaway from the link was just to create two separate queries.

Comment: Hibernate 4.3.11 supports use of JPA 2.0 so you should be able to use the typed parameters

Answer (score 4):

It looks the issue has not been resolved yet even with newer version of hibernate `5.2.17.Final` with JPA.

The null parameter is being sent as `VARBINARY` which causes the error

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to bigint
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround to this is to use the org.hibernate.Query that is wrapped into the org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl this way:

```
QueryImpl q = (QueryImpl) this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("myNamed.query");
q.getHibernateQuery().setParameter("name", value, org.hibernate.Hibernate.BIG_DECIMAL);
q.getResultList();
```

When `value` is null, hibernate still can know which type the parameter must be, so it doesn't translate the null to a binary value.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding 2 annotations

```
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
```

Also and most important, check mapping on your entity class for getters like (onetomany, manytoone).
All the best.